# How to merge multiple array into one?

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have splited address on my array now I want to merge all address into 1 
does anyone know to do it?

```
Array
(
   [address_street] => Level 01, No 1, First Avenue Bandar Utama

   [address_zip] => 47800

   [address_city] => Petaling Jaya

   [address_country] => Malaysia


   )
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)? Above example looks like a single array...

Comment: Merge address into 1 ? , you mean to have it as a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `implode` or do the following:

```
$mystring = $myarrayname['address_street'] . "<br />" . $myarrayname['address_city'] . " " . $myarrayname['address_zip'] . "<br />" . $myarrayname['address_country']; 
echo $mystring;
```

This will print

> Level 01, No 1, First Avenue Bandar Utama
>
> Petaling Jaya 47800
>
> Malaysia

Comment: Use of `"\n"` is always better. You can process `nl2br` when necessary for html after all xss clearing.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)  function to merge array elements into  string

```
    $array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');

    $comma_separated = implode(",", $array);

    echo $comma_separated; // lastname,email,phone
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use array_merge() in php which can merge two or more arrays.
EX.

```
<?php
$array1 = array("color" => "red", 2, 4);
$array2 = array("a", "b", "color" => "green", "shape" => "trapezoid", 4);
$array3 = array(1 => 'bar');
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2, $array3);
print_r($result);
?>
```